# How to get smooth gradient transition on a mesh

Tags: node-editor

I have multiple stretched cubes, which I have joined, and added a gradient node. but the gradient transition is not smooth, on the 4th cube the gradient is intersecting badly. How can I fix this?

Also on some shapes I cannot cannot control the gradient transition.

https://ibb.co/P5cHZMT

[image]

Comment: Turn the Mapping Scale smaller.

Answer (score 3):

First, you are using a geometry (shader) node as your texture coordinate - I suggest *generated* (texture coordinate node) instead, unless there's some specific reason for it. Also, if you "stretched" the cubes and joined them, make sure you have scale applied to the object (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > Scale in object mode). Then if you want the gradient to go "up and down" on the Z axis, separate the axes with a SeparateXYZ Node and just use the Z:

[image: Grad]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, worked well!